# Get bounds as GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I need the coordinates of the bounding box as a GeoJSON from PostGIS.

To do the calculations on the PostgreSQL server I use:

```
SELECT  ST_Extent(l.position_geo) AS box (...)
```

The answer is as expected a Box:

```
BOX(8.5359520687 47.3553607386,8.5458103273 47.3652211268)
```

So far so good.

But how can I convert this BOX into a GeoJSON for the transport to the client?

When I use :

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    ) AS geojson
from (
```

The geometry is missing.

There must be an easy way to form a simple GeoJSON with two points out of a BOX answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `BOX3D` back to a `GEOMETRY` for `ST_AsGeoJSON` to make sense of it:

```
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
         'type',     'FeatureCollection',
         'features', JSONB_AGG(ST_AsGeoJSON(q.*)::JSONB)
       ) AS fc
FROM   (
    SELECT 1 AS id,
           ST_Extent(ST_Expand('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 1))::GEOMETRY AS geom
) q
;
```

Note that `ST_Extent` is an ***aggregate function***, so the sub-select would need to be properly grouped to enclose anything but *all* geometries that you select! It may be easier to use `ST_Envelope` on individual geometries from the sub-select; it also returns `GEOMETRY` directly:

```
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
         'type',     'FeatureCollection',
         'features', JSONB_AGG(ST_AsGeoJSON(q.*)::JSONB)
       ) AS fc
FROM   (
    SELECT 1 AS id,
           ST_Envelope(ST_Expand('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 1)) AS geom
) q
;
```

---

If a per-feature BBOX is needed, the non-`RECORD` signatures will include them as OGC standard into the GeoJSON; extending the example from [@Encomiums (*deleted*) answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398395/93656), this

```
SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
         'type',     'FeatureCollection',
         'features', JSONB_AGG(feature)
       ) AS fc
FROM   (
  SELECT JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
           'type',       'Feature',
           'id',         id,
           'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, options => 1)::JSONB,
           'properties', TO_JSONB(r.*) - 'geom' - 'id'
         ) AS feature
  FROM   (
    SELECT 1 AS id,
           'foo' AS name,
           ST_Envelope(ST_Expand('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 1)) AS geom
  ) r
) q
;
```

would add a `bbox` member to each `feature`.

---

I wrote a set of [*custom aggregate functions*](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/b2e5cd65dd7f85ec381aeee14e0149ae) a while back that directly returns valid *FeatureCollection*s; while they center around the `RECORD` signature of `ST_AsGeoJSON` (not including a `bbox` member), they make the first examples a bit more convenient:

```
SELECT ST_AsFeatureCollection(q.*) AS geojson
FROM   (
    SELECT 1 AS id,
           ST_Envelope(ST_Expand('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 1)) AS geom
) q
;
```

Comment: Thank you. My task is to calculate the FlyTo Point and the zoom level for Mapbox for a layer with GeoJSOn feeded points. I calculate the flyto point with avg(ST_X(l.position_geo)) as center_lng, avg(ST_Y(l.position_geo)) as center_lat. Now with the box i want to finde the right zoom level to see all the points. Mybe there is a easier way. Is there a postgis function to find the maximum distance between the furthermost points?